# FileAppender with runtime defined file path

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I use log4j 2.x in our maven java war application running on jetty9.
All I need is follow structure:

1. Single point of code (function) lo log message.
2. Log function calls org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.[info, error ...] function.
3. log4j facility writes to main jetty9 log AND to log reside in appropriate folder defined on run time.

I have follow log4j2.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout 
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%-5L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I use follow dependency in maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And follow imports:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
```

And I try to make brainstorming voodoo with huge amount of log4j classes:

```
//Configuration c = new AbstractConfiguration
//PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
//FileAppender appender = new FileAppender("printlog", Layout.);
//logger.addAppender(null);
//OHH MY GOD!!!!
```

I searched a lot in documentation such as https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender but I don't find anything close to solve the problem.
All I found is manual for hardcode path to file appender in the configuration.
How to do it programmatically???
I need programmatically defined FileAppender inherits the PatternLayout from ConsoleAppender defined in xml config, because code reuse and single point of control issues.

Comment: Not exactly clear about what the issue your dealing with is. Is it that you want to configure an appender and log file location programmatically?
There are instructions on how to configure one [in the docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) if that's what you're looking for. But if it's just defining the log file, you can use system properties (i.e. "${sys:myProperty}")

Comment: OK, it seems what I need.